# Unable to download file from Snowflake table stage DecodeError('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.')

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I am new to Snowflake and was trying my hands on setting up a [Snowflake connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector.html) to pull data from Kafka and push it to Snowflake. I have successfully setup the pipeline and can see data being dumped into Snowflake table. As a part of checking out how troubleshooting works ( as described [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-ts.html) ) I was trying to use GET commnad to download file from the table stage onto my AWS EC2 instance via SnowSQL. This is the command I am using:

`get @KAFKA_DUMP.CDC_DATA.%MSKSNOWFLAKETESTTOPIC file:///home/ec2-user/;`

When I run this I get the following error:

```
+---------------------------------------------+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| file                                        | size | status | message                                                                                                                                                                            |
|---------------------------------------------+------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| MSKSnowflakeTestTopic/0/0_1638150345971.gz  |   -1 | ERROR  | ContentDecodingError(DecodeError('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',)),) |
| MSKSnowflakeTestTopic/0/0_1638160915637.gz  |   -1 | ERROR  | ContentDecodingError(DecodeError('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',)),) |
| MSKSnowflakeTestTopic/0/1_1638150346866.gz  |   -1 | ERROR  | ContentDecodingError(DecodeError('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',)),) |
| MSKSnowflakeTestTopic/0/20_1638150503432.gz |   -1 | ERROR  | ContentDecodingError(DecodeError('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',)),) |
| MSKSnowflakeTestTopic/0/20_1638153887230.gz |   -1 | ERROR  | ContentDecodingError(DecodeError('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',)),) |
```

I tried googling for this error but wasn't able to find anything specific to Snowflake GET.Hoping to get some help here.

**SnowSQL version** being used : 1.2.21
**OS:** Amazon Linux 2

**Error Log:**

```
2021-12-05 23:11:02,000 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_2) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent ERROR file_transfer_agent:577  - An exception was raised in <bound method SnowflakeS3RestClient.download_chunk of <snowflake.connector.s3_storage_client.SnowflakeS3RestClient object at 0x7f9a4412d358>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 401, in _decode
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 88, in decompress
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vendored/requests/models.py", line 758, in generate
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 576, in stream
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 548, in read
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 407, in _decode
snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.exceptions.DecodeError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file_transfer_agent.py", line 574, in function_and_callback_wrapper
  File "s3_storage_client.py", line 542, in download_chunk
  File "s3_storage_client.py", line 353, in _send_request_with_authentication_and_retry
  File "storage_client.py", line 278, in _send_request_with_retry
  File "vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
  File "vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 697, in send
  File "vendored/requests/models.py", line 836, in content
  File "vendored/requests/models.py", line 763, in generate
snowflake.connector.vendored.requests.exceptions.ContentDecodingError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))
2021-12-05 23:11:02,003 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_3) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:1237 - using OCSP response cache
2021-12-05 23:11:02,007 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_1) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:336  - Verifying the OCSP response is signed by the issuer.
2021-12-05 23:11:02,007 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_2) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:498  - Chunk 0/1 of file 2_1638150347764.gz reached callback
2021-12-05 23:11:02,010 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_3) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:293  - Certificate is attached in Basic OCSP Response
2021-12-05 23:11:02,013 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_3) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:296  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer
2021-12-05 23:11:02,013 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_3) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:300  - Valid Not After: 2022-09-01 07:00:00+00:00
2021-12-05 23:11:02,011 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_2) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:509  - Chunk 0 of file 2_1638150347764.gz failed to transfer for unexpected exception ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))
2021-12-05 23:11:02,016 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_2) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:514  - Chunk progress: 2_1638150347764.gz: completed: 0 failed: 1 total: 1
2021-12-05 23:11:02,017 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_2) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:534  - submitting 2_1638150347764.gz to done_postprocess
2021-12-05 23:11:02,018 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-27_6) snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connectionpool DEBUG connectionpool:461  - https://sfc-aus-ds1-6-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com:443 "HEAD /6ipo-s-aust1334/tables/9299208/CDCDataFromOracle/MSKSnowflakeTestTopic/0/30_1638155580009.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 0
2021-12-05 23:11:02,019 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-27_6) snowflake.connector.network DEBUG        network:1123 - Session status for SessionPool 'b'sfc-aus-ds1-6-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com'', SessionPool 3/15 active sessions
2021-12-05 23:11:02,019 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-28_0) snowflake.connector.storage_client ERROR storage_client:384  - Failed to download a file: /home/ec2-user/2_1638150347764.gz
NoneType: None
2021-12-05 23:11:02,020 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-28_0) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:543  - File 2_1638150347764.gz reached postprocess callback
2021-12-05 23:11:02,027 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_1) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:236  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer. Valid Not After: 2022-09-01 07:00:00+00:00
2021-12-05 23:11:02,028 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_1) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:682  - hit cache for subject: OrderedDict([('country_name', 'US'), ('state_or_province_name', 'Arizona'), ('locality_name', 'Scottsdale'), ('organization_name', 'Starfield Technologies, Inc.'), ('common_name', 'Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2')])
2021-12-05 23:11:02,031 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_1) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:1237 - using OCSP response cache
2021-12-05 23:11:02,034 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_1) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:293  - Certificate is attached in Basic OCSP Response
2021-12-05 23:11:02,034 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_1) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:296  - Verifying the attached certificate is signed by the issuer
2021-12-05 23:11:02,035 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_3) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:336  - Verifying the OCSP response is signed by the issuer.
2021-12-05 23:11:02,036 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_1) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:300  - Valid Not After: 2022-09-01 07:00:00+00:00
2021-12-05 23:11:02,036 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-27_6) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:451  - Finished preparing file 30_1638155580009.gz
2021-12-05 23:11:02,040 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_4) snowflake.connector.s3_storage_client DEBUG s3_storage_client:535  - Downloading chunk 0
2021-12-05 23:11:02,041 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_4) snowflake.connector.network DEBUG        network:1117 - Session status for SessionPool 'b'sfc-aus-ds1-6-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com'', SessionPool 4/15 active sessions
2021-12-05 23:11:02,042 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_4) snowflake.connector.storage_client DEBUG storage_client:277  - storage client request with session <snowflake.connector.vendored.requests.sessions.Session object at 0x7f9a4411d710>
2021-12-05 23:11:02,046 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_8) snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connectionpool DEBUG connectionpool:461  - https://sfc-aus-ds1-6-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com:443 "GET /6ipo-s-aust1334/tables/9299208/CDCDataFromOracle/MSKSnowflakeTestTopic/0/34_1638155580847.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 32
2021-12-05 23:11:02,047 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_8) snowflake.connector.network DEBUG        network:1123 - Session status for SessionPool 'b'sfc-aus-ds1-6-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com'', SessionPool 3/15 active sessions
2021-12-05 23:11:02,048 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_8) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent ERROR file_transfer_agent:577  - An exception was raised in <bound method SnowflakeS3RestClient.download_chunk of <snowflake.connector.s3_storage_client.SnowflakeS3RestClient object at 0x7f9a4412d6a0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 401, in _decode
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 88, in decompress
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vendored/requests/models.py", line 758, in generate
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 576, in stream
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 548, in read
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 407, in _decode
snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.exceptions.DecodeError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file_transfer_agent.py", line 574, in function_and_callback_wrapper
  File "s3_storage_client.py", line 542, in download_chunk
  File "s3_storage_client.py", line 353, in _send_request_with_authentication_and_retry
  File "storage_client.py", line 278, in _send_request_with_retry
  File "vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
  File "vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 697, in send
  File "vendored/requests/models.py", line 836, in content
  File "vendored/requests/models.py", line 763, in generate
snowflake.connector.vendored.requests.exceptions.ContentDecodingError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))
2021-12-05 23:11:02,052 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_8) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:498  - Chunk 0/1 of file 34_1638155580847.gz reached callback
2021-12-05 23:11:02,052 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_8) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:509  - Chunk 0 of file 34_1638155580847.gz failed to transfer for unexpected exception ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))
2021-12-05 23:11:02,053 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_8) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:514  - Chunk progress: 34_1638155580847.gz: completed: 0 failed: 1 total: 1
2021-12-05 23:11:02,053 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_8) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:534  - submitting 34_1638155580847.gz to done_postprocess
2021-12-05 23:11:02,056 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-28_4) snowflake.connector.storage_client ERROR storage_client:384  - Failed to download a file: /home/ec2-user/34_1638155580847.gz
NoneType: None
2021-12-05 23:11:02,056 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-28_4) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:543  - File 34_1638155580847.gz reached postprocess callback
2021-12-05 23:11:02,058 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_3) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:604  - writing OCSP response cache file to /root/.cache/snowflake/ocsp_response_cache.json
2021-12-05 23:11:02,058 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_3) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:1715 - encoding OCSP response cache to JSON
2021-12-05 23:11:02,064 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_1) snowflake.connector.ocsp_asn1crypto DEBUG ocsp_asn1crypto:336  - Verifying the OCSP response is signed by the issuer.
2021-12-05 23:11:02,088 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_4) snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connectionpool DEBUG connectionpool:461  - https://sfc-aus-ds1-6-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com:443 "GET /6ipo-s-aust1334/tables/9299208/CDCDataFromOracle/MSKSnowflakeTestTopic/0/30_1638155580009.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 32
2021-12-05 23:11:02,099 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_4) snowflake.connector.network DEBUG        network:1123 - Session status for SessionPool 'b'sfc-aus-ds1-6-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com'', SessionPool 2/15 active sessions
2021-12-05 23:11:02,099 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_4) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent ERROR file_transfer_agent:577  - An exception was raised in <bound method SnowflakeS3RestClient.download_chunk of <snowflake.connector.s3_storage_client.SnowflakeS3RestClient object at 0x7f9a4412d160>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 401, in _decode
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 88, in decompress
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vendored/requests/models.py", line 758, in generate
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 576, in stream
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 548, in read
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 407, in _decode
snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.exceptions.DecodeError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file_transfer_agent.py", line 574, in function_and_callback_wrapper
  File "s3_storage_client.py", line 542, in download_chunk
  File "s3_storage_client.py", line 353, in _send_request_with_authentication_and_retry
  File "storage_client.py", line 278, in _send_request_with_retry
  File "vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
  File "vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 697, in send
  File "vendored/requests/models.py", line 836, in content
  File "vendored/requests/models.py", line 763, in generate
snowflake.connector.vendored.requests.exceptions.ContentDecodingError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))
2021-12-05 23:11:02,102 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_4) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:498  - Chunk 0/1 of file 30_1638155580009.gz reached callback
2021-12-05 23:11:02,103 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_4) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:509  - Chunk 0 of file 30_1638155580009.gz failed to transfer for unexpected exception ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))
2021-12-05 23:11:02,103 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_4) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:514  - Chunk progress: 30_1638155580009.gz: completed: 0 failed: 1 total: 1
2021-12-05 23:11:02,104 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_4) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:534  - submitting 30_1638155580009.gz to done_postprocess
2021-12-05 23:11:02,105 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-28_5) snowflake.connector.storage_client ERROR storage_client:384  - Failed to download a file: /home/ec2-user/30_1638155580009.gz
NoneType: None
2021-12-05 23:11:02,105 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-28_5) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:543  - File 30_1638155580009.gz reached postprocess callback
2021-12-05 23:11:02,110 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_3) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:1115 - ok
2021-12-05 23:11:02,112 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_1) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:604  - writing OCSP response cache file to /root/.cache/snowflake/ocsp_response_cache.json
2021-12-05 23:11:02,112 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_1) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:1715 - encoding OCSP response cache to JSON
2021-12-05 23:11:02,153 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_1) snowflake.connector.ocsp_snowflake DEBUG ocsp_snowflake:1115 - ok
2021-12-05 23:11:02,202 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_3) snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connectionpool DEBUG connectionpool:461  - https://sfc-aus-ds1-6-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com:443 "GET /6ipo-s-aust1334/tables/9299208/CDCDataFromOracle/MSKSnowflakeTestTopic/0/59_1638161297797.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 32
2021-12-05 23:11:02,203 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_3) snowflake.connector.network DEBUG        network:1123 - Session status for SessionPool 'b'sfc-aus-ds1-6-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com'', SessionPool 1/15 active sessions
2021-12-05 23:11:02,204 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_3) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent ERROR file_transfer_agent:577  - An exception was raised in <bound method SnowflakeS3RestClient.download_chunk of <snowflake.connector.s3_storage_client.SnowflakeS3RestClient object at 0x7f9a41963128>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 401, in _decode
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 88, in decompress
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vendored/requests/models.py", line 758, in generate
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 576, in stream
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 548, in read
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 407, in _decode
snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.exceptions.DecodeError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file_transfer_agent.py", line 574, in function_and_callback_wrapper
  File "s3_storage_client.py", line 542, in download_chunk
  File "s3_storage_client.py", line 353, in _send_request_with_authentication_and_retry
  File "storage_client.py", line 278, in _send_request_with_retry
  File "vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
  File "vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 697, in send
  File "vendored/requests/models.py", line 836, in content
  File "vendored/requests/models.py", line 763, in generate
snowflake.connector.vendored.requests.exceptions.ContentDecodingError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))
2021-12-05 23:11:02,206 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_3) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:498  - Chunk 0/1 of file 59_1638161297797.gz reached callback
2021-12-05 23:11:02,207 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_3) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:509  - Chunk 0 of file 59_1638161297797.gz failed to transfer for unexpected exception ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))
2021-12-05 23:11:02,207 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_3) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:514  - Chunk progress: 59_1638161297797.gz: completed: 0 failed: 1 total: 1
2021-12-05 23:11:02,207 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_3) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:534  - submitting 59_1638161297797.gz to done_postprocess
2021-12-05 23:11:02,208 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-28_2) snowflake.connector.storage_client ERROR storage_client:384  - Failed to download a file: /home/ec2-user/59_1638161297797.gz
NoneType: None
2021-12-05 23:11:02,208 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-28_2) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:543  - File 59_1638161297797.gz reached postprocess callback
2021-12-05 23:11:02,209 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_1) snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.connectionpool DEBUG connectionpool:461  - https://sfc-aus-ds1-6-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com:443 "GET /6ipo-s-aust1334/tables/9299208/CDCDataFromOracle/MSKSnowflakeTestTopic/1/1_1638160916398.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 32
2021-12-05 23:11:02,210 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_1) snowflake.connector.network DEBUG        network:1123 - Session status for SessionPool 'b'sfc-aus-ds1-6-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com'', SessionPool 0/15 active sessions
2021-12-05 23:11:02,211 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_1) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent ERROR file_transfer_agent:577  - An exception was raised in <bound method SnowflakeS3RestClient.download_chunk of <snowflake.connector.s3_storage_client.SnowflakeS3RestClient object at 0x7f9a419638d0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 401, in _decode
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 88, in decompress
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vendored/requests/models.py", line 758, in generate
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 576, in stream
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 548, in read
  File "vendored/urllib3/response.py", line 407, in _decode
snowflake.connector.vendored.urllib3.exceptions.DecodeError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file_transfer_agent.py", line 574, in function_and_callback_wrapper
  File "s3_storage_client.py", line 542, in download_chunk
  File "s3_storage_client.py", line 353, in _send_request_with_authentication_and_retry
  File "storage_client.py", line 278, in _send_request_with_retry
  File "vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
  File "vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 697, in send
  File "vendored/requests/models.py", line 836, in content
  File "vendored/requests/models.py", line 763, in generate
snowflake.connector.vendored.requests.exceptions.ContentDecodingError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))
2021-12-05 23:11:02,213 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_1) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:498  - Chunk 0/1 of file 1_1638160916398.gz reached callback
2021-12-05 23:11:02,214 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_1) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:509  - Chunk 0 of file 1_1638160916398.gz failed to transfer for unexpected exception ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))
2021-12-05 23:11:02,214 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_1) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:514  - Chunk progress: 1_1638160916398.gz: completed: 0 failed: 1 total: 1
2021-12-05 23:11:02,214 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-26_1) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:534  - submitting 1_1638160916398.gz to done_postprocess
2021-12-05 23:11:02,215 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-28_1) snowflake.connector.storage_client ERROR storage_client:384  - Failed to download a file: /home/ec2-user/1_1638160916398.gz
NoneType: None
2021-12-05 23:11:02,215 (10061/ThreadPoolExecutor-28_1) snowflake.connector.file_transfer_agent DEBUG file_transfer_agent:543  - File 1_1638160916398.gz reached postprocess callback
2021-12-05 23:11:02,216 (10061/MainThread) snowflake.connector.cursor DEBUG         cursor:823  - Query result format: json
2021-12-05 23:11:02,216 (10061/MainThread) snowflake.connector.converter_snowsql DEBUG converter_snowsql:88   - Type: TEXT, Format: None
2021-12-05 23:11:02,217 (10061/MainThread) snowflake.connector.converter_snowsql DEBUG converter_snowsql:88   - Type: FIXED, Format: None
2021-12-05 23:11:02,218 (10061/MainThread) snowflake.connector.converter_snowsql DEBUG converter_snowsql:88   - Type: TEXT, Format: None
2021-12-05 23:11:02,218 (10061/MainThread) snowflake.connector.converter_snowsql DEBUG converter_snowsql:88   - Type: TEXT, Format: None
2021-12-05 23:11:02,219 (10061/MainThread) snowflake.connector.result_batch DEBUG   result_batch:442  - parsing for result batch id: 21
2021-12-05 23:11:02,219 (10061/MainThread) snowflake.connector.result_set DEBUG     result_set:72   - beginning to schedule result batch downloads
2021-12-05 23:11:02,220 (10061/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      eventloop:723  - headers: [('file', 2), ('size', 0), ('status', 2), ('message', 2)]
2021-12-05 23:11:02,220 (10061/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      eventloop:729  - rows: '[[\'MSKSnowflakeTestTopic/0/0_1638150345971.gz\', \'-1\', \'ERROR\', "ContentDecodingError(DecodeError(\'Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.\', error(\'Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check\',)),)"], [\'MSKS...'
2021-12-05 23:11:02,223 (10061/MainThread) snowflake.cli.tabulate DEBUG       tabulate:642  - minwidths: [43, 4, 6, 178]
2021-12-05 23:11:02,223 (10061/MainThread) snowflake.cli.tabulate DEBUG       tabulate:651  - headers: ['file                                       ', 'size', 'status', 'message                                                                                                                                                                           '], minwidths: [43, 4, 6, 178]
2021-12-05 23:11:02,226 (10061/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      eventloop:822  - Command Time: 7.607525587081909
2021-12-05 23:11:02,226 (10061/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      eventloop:794  - end of SQL: get @KAFKA_DUMP.CDC_DATA.%MSKSNOWFLAKETESTTOPIC file:///home/ec2-user/;
2021-12-05 23:11:02,228 (10061/MainThread) __main__ DEBUG      eventloop:694  - Read from terminal
```

Comment: What is the SnowSQL version you used?

Comment: It is 1.2.21. I have added it to my description now.

Comment: Can you enable [DEBUG](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#snowsql) log level for SnowSQL and provide the log? What operating system are you using?

Comment: Added the error log and OS to the description

Comment: I think there is something wrong with HTTP headers. Are you able to upload a test file using SnowSQL and PUT and then download it using GET?

Answer (score 1):

Run snowsql with additional parameter: "-v 1.2.17"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

running version 1.2.17 worked for me.

Comment: This is just validating [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71702615/3025856). Please don't duplicate previous answers as a way of saying **"thank you"** or of validating their guidance. Instead, once you have established a bit of reputation, you can upvote answers you found useful.